# Define ordering scheme for user defined domain type

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a domain like

```
CREATE DOMAIN my_type AS TEXT NOT NULL;
```

And a table

```
CREATE TABLE my_types (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    my_value my_type
);

INSERT INTO my_types (my_value) VALUES ('not an asterisk'), ('*'), ('also not an asterisk');
```

I can define a sorting function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
sort_my_type(my_type)
RETURNS INT LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF $1 = '*' THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

And use it to order my query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_types ORDER BY sort_my_type(my_value);
```

Which makes sure that any value that equals '*' will be first.

How can I drop the need to specify the function? I'm not really interested in implementing comparison functions (unless I need to), I just want to define a "natural order" for `my_type`. It seems to essentially inherit its default ordering scheme from TEXT as of now.

So the desired outcome is that the query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM my_types ORDER BY my_value;
```

(This *happens* to work currently, because my desired outcome in this example happens to coincide with how TEXT is ordered. The real example is a little more thorough and cannot rely on the default ordering of text.)

Comment: You can't do this with `DOMAIN` because that is essentially a subset of an existing type -- unless there is a collation that matches what you want.  You could define a customer collation, but that might be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Shame, but thank you. If you would like to, feel free to write an answer saying the same, and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Gordon Linoff's:

> You can't do this with DOMAIN because that is essentially a subset of an existing type -- unless there is a collation that matches what you want. You could define a customer collation, but that might be more trouble than it is worth